# How can I constrain a Swift protocol to a concrete type?

Tags: generics, swift

Take a look at the following hypothetical code:

```
class Stream<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element: Character> {
    init(_ sequence: S) {}
}
```

Doesn't compile. I get "S.Generator.Element constrained to non-protocol type Character". This is a bummer, man. I've thought of two possibilities:

```
class Stream<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element: ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralType> {
}
```

This constraint works because `Character` is the only thing I know of to implement that protocol. The problem is that now I have an `ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralType` instead of a `Character` so I'm forced to cast, which I can live with.

The other possibility is just to define my own protocol, e.g., `CharacterType`, and have `Character` implement that through an extension.  (This is probably also safer.) This is likely the approach I will actually take, but I wondered if anyone knew a way around this limitation other than this one?

Comment: "The other possibility is just to define my own protocol, e.g., CharacterType, and have Character implement that through an extension". That is what I was going to suggest. I tested it and it works fine. I don't understand why you see this as a "limitation".

Comment: As limitations go, it's not a terrible one. But it'd be nice to avoid a cast that could in theory fail, even if in practice that's never going to happen, and I'm spoiled by languages like Haskell and C# that do allow such things. For instance, the equivalent in C# would be to say `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: I'm exploring some ideas but I have a feeling I'm not going to succeed. :( As many have said, Swift is not Haskell...

Comment: Not only is it not Haskell, but it's also at 1.0 (though I think "1.0" was a bit optimistic of them). I really hope Swift 2.0 will address some of the pain points in the type system. It's a common topic of conversation between me and my shrink.

Comment: The really dumb thing about this is that I already knew the answer and I just had a weird lapse. I forgot about the `==` syntax as opposed to `:`, and when `:` didn't work, well…

Comment: Well, I look dumb too, but I don't care. I actually learned something from this, and I'm really glad it happened.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
class Stream<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Character> {
//                                                     ^^
    init(_ sequence: S) {}
}
```

Comment: D'oh! I can't believe it was that simple.

Comment: I actually feel kind of dumb.

Comment: No no I told you Rintaro would know!

Comment: I think I skipped on swift basics class too early ! Could you please expand as to why `:` didnt work and `==` works ?

Comment: @GoodSp33d I think it can be summed up as `:` means "implements" while `==` means "is (a subtype of)". I don't understand why they made a distinction, since the compiler can always tell from the RHS which one is meant. But it is what it is.